# How do I define a PasswordEncoder using annotations in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I am using Spring-Boot v1.3.0.M2. I am trying to define a `o.s.s.c.p.PasswordEncoder` using annotations. My configuration class looks like the following. This example works fine.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 @Bean
 public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() { 
  return new StandardPasswordEncoder();
 }
}
```

However, I would like to instantiate the `StandardPasswordEncoder` with a secret, and I've revised my class as follows.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 @Autowired
 @Value(value="${password.secret}")
 private String secret;

 @Bean
 public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() { 
  return new StandardPasswordEncoder(secret);
 }
}
```

Please note my Spring-Boot application looks like the following.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:/config/myapp.properties")
public class Application {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplications.run(Application.class, args);
 }

 @Bean
 public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer getPropertySourcesPlaceholdConfigurer() {
  return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
 }
}
```

And my `myapp.properties` looks like the following.

```
password.secret=fsdkjfsldfsdfsdfsdf
```

When I try to run my Spring-Boot application, I get the following exception.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'webSecurityConfig' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'getPasswordEncoder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 102 more
```

The `PasswordEncoder` couldn't be instantiated because the field `private String secret;` is not set, and thus the `NullPointerException` (NPE). I tried making the method `getPasswordEncoder` static as well as the field `secret`, but that doesn't help.

Any ideas on how I can use annotations to get an instance of `PasswordEncoder` with a secret?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by tinkering a bit. I removed the field `secret` and simply annotated the parameter with the method instead as follows.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 @Bean
 public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder(@Value(value="${password.secret}") String secret) { 
  return new StandardPasswordEncoder(secret);
 }
}
```

Comment: It should also work with the field, i think the Autowired annotation was the problem, since you don't need that, if you have the Value annotation on a field.

Answer (score 1):

A bcrypt password encryptor, which [Spring recommends](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-password-encoder)  over SHA or MD5, can be configured like this:

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
  return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```